# Rally API 2.0 model vs models

Tags: javascript, rally

I have created a custom kanban board.  Inside the board, I have a button on the cards for someone to claim when they are going to code review an item.  Upon clicking the button, I wanted to go check the live data to ensure nobody else claimed since the screen was loaded.

I have all that working if its a story, but if its a defect I had an issue.  So in reviewing the code, I noticed I did a `Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel` then a `model.load`.

So I am thinking this should be changed to `.getModels` and change types to incorporate both stories and defect.  However, when I do this, how do I get that into the search properly.  I am getting stuck with how to load it up and check.

Code snippet is:

```
if (this.getRecord().get("StoryStatus") == "Review Ready") {
                    if (this.getRecord().get("CodeReviewedBy") == '') {
                        content.add([{ xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'I will review',
                            scale: 'small',
                            listeners: {
                                click: function (btn, e, eOpts) {
                                    // Verify nobody has claimed it yet !
                                    var mod = Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels({
                                        types: ['HierarchicalRequirement', 'Defect'],
                                        success: function (models) {
                                            var model;
                                            debugger;
                                            if (models.Defect) model = models.Defect
                                            else model = models.HierarchicalRequirement;

                                            model.load(eOpts.scope.record.internalId, {
                                                fetch: ['CodeReviewedBy'],
                                                success: function (currentRecord) {
                                                    var currentCRB = currentRecord.get("CodeReviewedBy");
                                                    if (currentCRB) {
                                                        window.alert('While you were sitting around doing nothing, ' + currentCRB + ' already started reviewing this code');
                                                    } else {
                                                        var con = Rally.environment.getContext();
                                                        currentRecord.set("CodeReviewedBy", con.context.user._refObjectName);
                                                        currentRecord.save();
                                                        location.reload(true);
                                                        //eOpts.scope.refresh();
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                    this.refresh()
                                },
                                scope: this
                            }
                        }]);
                    } else {
                        content.add([{ xtype: 'label',
                            html: '<b>Being reviewed by: </b>' + this.getRecord().get("CodeReviewedBy") + '<br>'
                        }]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I know its not the best code, but hopefully it can still be followed.  I am having the problems around that debugger statement, seems like I have to get the models, which returns what all the stories and defects??  Just not clicking and making sense.  Basically looking to find if the CodeReviewer field is still empty in the database realtime for the story/defect.  Seems I am making it too complicated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the record you can actually use the self property to get the model- that will save you having to use ModelFactory.getModels again.

```
var model = this.getRecord().self;
model.load(this.getRecord().get('ObjectID'), {
    //fetch, success, etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that did the trick.  I actually changed it a bit to grab the type and use it in the getodels.types, this way it only loads the model it needs.  Thanks for the tip !